# Why won't my UIWebView display a Javascript YouTube player iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, flash

I am created a UIWebView in Objective-C using a storyboard object and this code.

```
[videoView setDelegate:self];
NSString *preURL = @"http://example.com/videoscript.php";
NSString *fullURL = [preURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[videoView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

The WebView opens a link with this content

```
<head>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api?enablejsapi=1&version=3"></script>

        <script language="javascript">
    //Load player api asynchronously.
    //var tag = document.createElement('script');
    //tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  //  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    //firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    //var done = false;
    //var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          },
          playerVars: {
              'controls': '0',
              'showinfo': '0',
              'showsearch': '0',
              'loop': '1',
              'embedjsapi': '1',
              'qutoplay': '1'
          }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(evt) {
        evt.target.playVideo();
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {

    }
    function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
    }

        </script>
</head>
```

The confusing part is that the script functions fine in a desktop browser but on Safari for iOS and in UIWebView's it does not work. I assume this is a lack of Adobe Flash Player issue but I thought that creating a iFrame using javascript was the same as using the actual  tags? When I use the  tags this does work but that method is not an option for me. So my question is, is there anyway to embed an HTML5 YouTube player using Javascript and not iFrames directly?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) you are using does require Flash Player and therefore will not work on iOS. Under "Requirements" it says:

> The end user must have Flash Player 10.1 or higher installed to view everything correctly. Because of this requirement, we suggest using SWFObject to embed the SWF and detect the user's Flash Player version.

Note that an iFrame simply embeds another document and doesn't necessarily imply anything else about what that document is–it could still be a Flash Player embed.

If you're looking to easily circumvent the Flash Player issue, the following JavaScript would certainly work in a UIWebView. It won't provide the same level of customization for the player though.

```
var iframe = $("<iframe>");

iframe.attr({
    width: "100%",
    frameborder: 0,
    src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY"    
});

// Or, append directly to body.
$("#viewport").append(iframe);
```

Just switch this line in your iOS app to the [demo url](http://jsfiddle.net/KrshC/1/) for testing.

```
NSString *preURL = @"http://jsfiddle.net/KrshC/1/embedded/result/";
```